# Polymorphism in Golang

Tags: oop, go, polymorphism

It's simple example what I want:

I have object of B and use function step1 from struct A (common functionality). I need to redefine function step2 for B which runs inside A.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {}

func (a *A) step1() {
    a.step2();
}

func (a *A) step2 () {
   fmt.Println("get A");
}


type B struct {
   A
}

func (b *B) step2 () {
   fmt.Println("get B");
}

func main() {
    obj := B{}
    obj.step1() 
}
```

How can I do it?

```
// maybe 
func step1(a *A) {
   self.step2(a);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to rethink your model because method overriding simply does not work with Go's constructs for OOP. Like if you embed A in B and then call a method C that was defined on both A and B, which version is invoked isn't even defined; there are no method resolution rules in the spec. Don't try to do it. Whatever you want to accomplish can be done equally effectively with slightly different relationships between objects.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: it's not undefined, it's defined as ambiguous. You'll get a compile time error that says "ambiguous selector" if there are conflicting embedded identifiers.

Comment: @Harlam: you can't structure go types as if there's inheritance. The embedded type can't call the outer type (and knows nothing about it), since embedding is nothing more than automatic delegation. There is no `step2` for B inside of A, there is only a shorthand version of `B.A.step1()`.

Comment: @JimB I'm not sure what you mean... I can embed a type `A` which contains a method `C` into a type `B` which also contains a definition for a method `C` and I can compile and run the program and when I call `B.C()` the behavior is undefined - ie the spec mentions nothing about how method resolution is handled, unlike say C# which gives a list of rules which would guarantee me the execution of B's version of C rather than A's.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: your [description of this code](http://play.golang.org/p/BPDZP3Lzwt) is perfectly valid - that's how you "override" an embedded method, and we do it all the time. If there's multiple possible fields ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/b_2Ivi3wcB)), then you get compile error. The [spec on selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) is very clear on this, and there's certainly no undefined behavior.

Comment: @JimB oh I see. that makes more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go doesn't do polymorphism.  You have to recast what you want to do in terms of interfaces, and functions (not methods) that take those interfaces.

So think what interface does each object need to satisfy, then what functions you need to work on that interface.  There are lots of great examples in the go standard library, eg `io.Reader`, `io.Writer` and the functions which work on those, eg `io.Copy`.

[Here is my attempt](http://play.golang.org/p/BluerSTorq) to recast your example into that style.  It doesn't make a lot of sense, but hopefully it will give you something to work on.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
}

type steps interface {
    step1()
    step2()
}

func (a *A) step1() {
    fmt.Println("step1 A")
}

func (a *A) step2() {
    fmt.Println("get A")
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (b *B) step2() {
    fmt.Println("get B")
}

func step1(f steps) {
    f.step1()
    f.step2()
}

func main() {
    obj := B{}
    step1(&obj)
}
```